# Modify a file with R at a given position

Tags: regex, r, text, replace

How can I modify a text file with R at a given position?

It's not a table but any file, for example an xml file.

For example to replace the content of line 122 from columns 7  (to 10) by the content of a variable, that is "3.14".

and update the file.

Imagine that line was

```
<name=0.32>
```

now should be

```
<name=3.14>
```

Or another option, maybe easier.
Look for all aparitions of occurences of "Variable=" and change the next 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to read in the entire file and then use string manipulation. E.g.,

```
f <- "file.xml"
x <- readLines(f)
x[122] <- paste0(substring(x[122], 1, 8), "3.14", substring(x[122], 13, nchar(x[122])))
writeLines(x, f)
```

I assume there is a command-line tool that would be better suited to this.

Comment: I was wondering what commands are better, because there are others, such as scan.  I'll try. Thanks

Comment: Maybe python, but I don't know how to do it either

Comment: It works well, thanks. I tried to do it with R because I also need to do more things.  Now I have to create a loop to try many different random values.
Anyway I need to call (execute) a Windows program at every step, that program reads the new file.  I don't know if it's possible. I'll try with system("program with options")

Comment: @skan Yes, `system()` is what you want for that or perhaps `shell()`.

Comment: But will R know when has the external program ended in order to jump to the next loop?.

Comment: @skan Yes, the default behavior is governed by a `wait` argument. If you set that to FALSE, R will not wait. If TRUE, it will wait for the external command to complete before proceeding.